# How change QueryDSL findAll return type from Iterable to Stream?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

How to change QueryDSL findAll return type from Iterable to Stream ?

wanted like below :

```
interface StudentRepo extends JpaRepository,QuerydslPredicateExecutor{
   Stream<Student> findAll(Predicate predicate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I follow.

You need `findAll` to return a `Stream`? You can't do that, as the `JpaRepository` superinterface already defines a method like that, with an incompatible return type.

You can, however, use any of the other [supported method name prefixes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords) like `readAll` or `searchAll`.

I don't quite see how QueryDSL comes into the picture, though.

Comment: I edited the code, actually i want to pass predicate which having multiple condition inside findAll

Comment: Oh, OK. In that case the answer is, sadly, you can't. To use QueryDSL with spring repositories, you need to do that via one of the predefined methods from `QueryDslPredicateExecutor`, there's no way to customize the return values